# Is there a way to iterate down rows and across columns and compile that data into a cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I  am trying to compile data from one sheet containing order information to another sheets cell based on each customers name. I'd like to take the title of the column as well as the count for the item(s) they have ordered. I tried to brute force it with a formula in Google Sheets but the formula messes up and stops giving the correct information so I figured using a scripts function would be better for what I am trying to do. I made a new sheet to test a script on but have little experience and can't seem to make any progress.

I'd like to get the title(top row) of each column and the count of the item(s) into the order column on sheet2 base on the matching names on both sheets. If anyone could help or provide some insight it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code I came up with:

```
 function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var orders = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var data = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var names = orders.getRange("Sheet2!A2:A5");
  var name = names.getValues();
  var startRow = 1
var endRow = ss.getLastRow()
var getRange = ss.getDataRange();
  var getRow = getRange.getRow();
  var title = data.getRange("Sheet1!B1:J1");
  var item = title.getValues();
  var itemCell = data.getRange("Sheet1!B2").getValue();
  var orderCell = orders.getRange(2,2).getValue()
  
  Logger.log(itemCell)
   
  if(itemCell>=0){
    orders.getRange(2,2).setValue("item1 x " +itemCell)
  }
```

currently this only has the desired effect on one cell and does not complete the row and repeat on next column.

Here is how I adjusted the code to try and fit a larger data set:

```
function myFunction() {
  const srcSheetName = "Test Data";
  const dstSheetName = "Order Changes";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // 1. Retrieve source values.
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  //I changed values  1,1 to change the values that were retreived
  const [[, ...header], ...srcValues] = srcSheet.getRange(1, 1, 
  srcSheet.getLastRow(), srcSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
  // 2. Create an object using the source values.
  const srcObj = srcValues.reduce((o, [a, ...v]) => {
    const temp = v.reduce((s, r, i) => {
      if (r.toString() != "") s += `${header[i]} ${r}`;
      return s;
    }, "");
    return Object.assign(o, {[a]: temp || ""});
  }, {});
  
  // 3. Retrieve the header column of destination values.
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  //I changed values 2 or 1 to adjust the destination of values
  const dstRange = dstSheet.getRange(2, 1, dstSheet.getLastRow() - 1);
  const dstValues = dstRange.getValues();
  
  // 4. Create the output values using the header column and the object.
  const putValues = dstValues.map(([a]) => [srcObj[a] || ""]);
  
  // 5. Put the values.
  dstRange.offset(0, 1).setValues(putValues);
}
```

after making the changes and running the code the values would either not appear or appear in the wrong column with incorrect data.

Goal of function Update:

1. Match names in Sheet2!A with names in Sheet1!F
2. If a match is found combine header and value of cells in Sheet1!N1:BQ.
   This should be from the same row of the matched name in Sheet1!F (example:
   John Smith lm14 1, lm25 2, lm36 1)
3. Place combined data into Sheet2!C
4. Repeat for every name in Sheet2!A

header and cell value should not be combined if value < 0

I hope this helps to clarify any misunderstanding.

Here is are better example images:

[image: Sheet1 highlighting example in Sheet2]
[image: Sheet2 with example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- In your goal, the upper image in your question is the output you expect, and the cells "B2" should be `item1 1 item3 1 item6 2 item9 3` when the lower input situation is used.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In order to achieve above, I would like to propose the following flow.

1. Retrieve source values.
2. Create an object using the source values.
3. Retrieve the header column of destination values.
4. Create the output values using the header column and the object.
5. Put the values.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of the Spreadsheet and set the source sheet name and destination sheet name, and run `myFunction`.

```
function myFunction() {
  const srcSheetName = "Sheet1";
  const dstSheetName = "Sheet2";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // 1. Retrieve source values.
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  const [[, ...header], ...srcValues] = srcSheet.getRange(1, 1, srcSheet.getLastRow(), srcSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
  // 2. Create an object using the source values.
  const srcObj = srcValues.reduce((o, [a, ...v]) => {
    const temp = v.reduce((s, r, i) => {
      if (r.toString() != "") s += `${header[i]} ${r}`;
      return s;
    }, "");
    return Object.assign(o, {[a]: temp || ""});
  }, {});
  
  // 3. Retrieve the header column of destination values.
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  const dstRange = dstSheet.getRange(2, 1, dstSheet.getLastRow() - 1);
  const dstValues = dstRange.getValues();
  
  // 4. Create the output values using the header column and the object.
  const putValues = dstValues.map(([a]) => [srcObj[a] || ""]);
  
  // 5. Put the values.
  dstRange.offset(0, 1).setValues(putValues);
}
```

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

### Added 1:

About your current issue, the reason of your issue is that the ranges of source and destination are the different from the sample image in your question. My suggested answer is for the sample images in your initial question. When you changed the structure of the Spreadsheet, it is required to modify my suggested script. But from `I changed values  1,1 to change the values that were retrieved` and `I changed values 2 or 1 to adjust the destination of values`, I couldn't understand about your modified script. So as the additional script, I would like to modify my suggested answer for your updated question.

From your updated question and replyings, I understood that the source range and destination range are "N1:BQ" and "A52:C79", respectively. From this, please modify above sample script as follows.

#### From:

```
const [[, ...header], ...srcValues] = srcSheet.getRange(1, 1, srcSheet.getLastRow(), srcSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
```

#### To:

```
const [[, ...header], ...srcValues] = srcSheet.getRange("N1:BQ" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
```

and

#### From:

```
dstRange.offset(0, 1).setValues(putValues);
```

#### To:

```
dstRange.offset(0, 2).setValues(putValues);
```

### Added 2:

About your current issue, the reason of your issue is that the ranges of source and destination are the different from your 1st updated question in your question. My suggested answer is for the sample images in your 1st updated question. When you changed the structure of the Spreadsheet, it is required to modify my suggested script.

From your 2nd updated question, I understood that the source range and destination range are "F1:BQ" (the column "F" is the title and the columns "N1:BQ" are the values.) and "A2:C", respectively. From this, please modify above sample script as follows.

```
function myFunction() {
  const srcSheetName = "Sheet1";
  const dstSheetName = "Sheet2";
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  
  // 1. Retrieve source values.
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  const [[,,,,,,,, ...header], ...srcValues] = srcSheet.getRange("F1:BQ" + srcSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // 2. Create an object using the source values.
  const srcObj = srcValues.reduce((o, [a,,,,,,,, ...v]) => {
    const temp = v.reduce((s, r, i) => {
      if (r.toString() != "") s += `${header[i]} ${r}`;
      return s;
    }, "");
    return Object.assign(o, {[a]: temp || ""});
  }, {});
  
  // 3. Retrieve the header column of destination values.
  const dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  const dstRange = dstSheet.getRange(2, 1, dstSheet.getLastRow() - 1);
  const dstValues = dstRange.getValues();
  
  // 4. Create the output values using the header column and the object.
  const putValues = dstValues.map(([a]) => [srcObj[a] || ""]);

  console.log(srcObj)

  // 5. Put the values.
  dstRange.offset(0, 2).setValues(putValues);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! the result is not quite what I am looking to do. I have written up some code since the post. B2 should look like this "item1 1" I have gotten my code to do that but don't know how to repeat the process for all the cells in the  row and continue the process down each column.

I'll add what I have written to the original post.

Comment: @Dan.db Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience and my poor English skill. From your replying, I understood the cell "B2" should be `B2 should look like this "item1 1"`. In this case, `item1 1` is put to the cell "B2" of the destination sheet? If my understanding is correct, can I ask you about the other cells of the destination sheet? I would like to correctly understand about your goal.

Comment: Of course! In the example image of sheet1, John (Cell A2), has ordered one item1, one item 3, two item6 and three item9. My goal is to return the value of the cell combined with the title of the column into the order column on Sheet2.

John's order (Sheet2!B2) would look like this: item1 1 item3 1 item6 2 item9 3

This pattern would continue for each name listed in column A of Sheet1

Comment: @Dan.db Thank you for replying. From your replying, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize again.

Comment: Oh wow! You did it! Thank you! Now I'll just need to figure out how it all works so I can apply it to the real document. Thanks again!

Comment: @Dan.db Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying and the current situation, I'm worry whether my suggested answer could resolve your issue. If my answer was not useful for your situation, I apologize.

Comment: You have helped me!

Comment: @Dan.db Is there anything that I can do for your question? If my answer was not useful for your situation. I have to apologize and modify it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. I would like to think of about the solution.

Comment: I tried to use the provided solution on a larger data set but could not get it to work so I decided to focus on another problem instead.

Comment: @Dan.db Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In order to correctly understand about the current issue of my suggested answer, can you provide the detail information of your sample input and output you expect and the detail flow for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Dan.db Thank you for adding more information. From `I changed values  1,1 to change the values that were retrieved` and `I changed values 2 or 1 to adjust the destination of values`, in this case, it is required to know your Spreadsheet and your current script. Because my given information is the image in your question. In this case, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the input and output you expect for replicating the issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: I cannot provide an image of the actual spreadsheet because it is very large  and contains information that is not mine. The source values for the list of items (item1, item2,...)  is from N:BQ and the destination range is from C52:C79. Every name is in column F of test Data. The names I want to find are in range A52:A79 of Order Changes

Comment: @Dan.db Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood the reason of your issue. The reason of your issue is that the ranges of source and destination are the different from the sample image in your question.

Comment: @Dan.db So in order to correctly understand about your actual situation, can you update the images in your question using the sample values you can show? Because from `The source values for the list of items (item1, item2,...) is from N:BQ and the destination range is from C52:C79. Every name is in column F of test Data. The names I want to find are in range A52:A79 of Order Changes`, I cannot image your situation. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @Dan.db Thank updating it. From your updated question, I proposed the modification point for achieving your updated situation. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize. At that time, I think that it is required to know the sample Spreadsheet for replicating the actual situation.

Comment: The text still goes to the incorrect location and has the incorrect values. I will try to update the post again if you are still willing to help.

Comment: @Dan.db Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience. For your 2nd updated question, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it?